# Master theorem cases

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, master-theorem

My question is about [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem). 
Are there any cases in which *a >= 1* and *b > 1*, but Master theorem does not work?
Can you give an example, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the recurrence

```
T(n) = 4T(n/2) + n^2 * log n
```

None of the three cases applies because there does not exist an `e` such that `log n = Ω(n^e)` or `log n = O(n^(-e))`